403 Error when downloading Solana install tool
I am attempting to download the Solana CLI on my Ubuntu cloud server. Here is the download script I run:
sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/stable/install)"

When I do this, I get a 403 error:
downloading stable installer
enter preformatted text here`curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 403
solana-install-init: command failed: downloader https://release.solana.com/stable/solana-install-init-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu /tmp/tmp.of7BLS5NSP/solana-install-init

At this time, I have tried:

Downloading prebuilt binaries
Building from source
Rebooting my machine
Waiting about a day and trying again

I added a verbose flag to my script and ran it again. Here are the results:
*   Trying 18.238.85.55:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to release.solana.com (18.238.85.55) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [512 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [122 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
{ [19 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
{ [4962 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
{ [264 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
{ [36 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
} [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
} [36 bytes data]
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=release.solana.com
*  start date: Sep 22 00:00:00 2023 GMT
*  expire date: Oct 21 23:59:59 2024 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "release.solana.com" matched cert's "release.solana.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Amazon; CN=Amazon RSA 2048 M03
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
} [5 bytes data]
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0xaaaae3557e90)
} [5 bytes data]
> GET /stable/install HTTP/2
> Host: release.solana.com
> user-agent: curl/7.68.0
> accept: */*
>
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
{ [124 bytes data]
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 128)!
} [5 bytes data]
< HTTP/2 200
< content-type: binary/octet-stream
< content-length: 5052
< date: Wed, 10 Apr 2024 01:51:38 GMT
< last-modified: Sun, 03 Mar 2024 06:52:31 GMT
< etag: "f47504c9f2e1c2cf373db5433399e027"
< x-amz-server-side-encryption: AES256
< accept-ranges: bytes
< server: AmazonS3
< x-cache: Miss from cloudfront
< via: 1.1 43d7135d078d4d8e84b4e09ae5af0800.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
< x-amz-cf-pop: PHX52-P1
< x-amz-cf-id: -QitZ34N52Ymus-YZnGBoqNiXCaqTYziv5o5XUXxbAm2bvb2rha7BQ==
<
{ [5052 bytes data]
* Connection #0 to host release.solana.com left intact
downloading stable installer
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 403
solana-install-init: command failed: downloader https://release.solana.com/stable/solana-install-init-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu /tmp/tmp.SDxhwXLOSx/solana-install-init

To be honest, I don't see any issues in the verbose log. If anything, downloading the file seems to work ok, but running the installer (which may have another similar curl script inside) returns an error.
If anyone has the same issue or knows how to fix it, please let me know. I can provide more details upon request.
Thank you.

Does this still happen? I just tried it locally here and it worked fine

@JonasH.Yes. However, I don't want to run it locally. I plan to run it on the Oracle Cloud server.

Judging by the release URL, it looks like you're trying to download an installer for Linux on ARM: https://release.solana.com/stable/solana-install-init-aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
There are only binaries provided for x86_64 on Linux, Mac, and Windows, and aarch64 is only for Mac.
You can see in the list of assets in the release at https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/releases/tag/v1.18.11 that there's no Linux aarch64 build.
Until that build is provided by the release pipeline, you'll have to build the binaries yourself unfortunately.
